# undefined local variable or method error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I have a method in controller -

```
def undo_link
  view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@page.versions.scoped.last), :method => :post)
end
```

But when i call it in views with  `"#{undo_link}"` . I get the 
undefined local variable or method error .

what am i doing wrong ?

Update : Here the revert method in the controller

okay but then this is the revert method i got in the controller

```
def revert
  @version = Version.find(params[:id])
  if @version.reify
    @version.reify.save!
  else
    @version.item.destroy
  end
  link_name = params[:redo] == "true" ? "undo" : "redo"
  link = view_context.link_to(link_name, revert_version_path(@version.next, :redo => !params[:redo]), :method => :post)
  redirect_to :back, :notice => "Undid #{@version.event}. #{link}"
end
```

Comment: What makes you think you can call arbitrary controller methods from the view? Maybe you're thinking of creating a helper?

Comment: Well i tried that, but it messes up the routes. view_context gives a no method error

Comment: you don't need view_context n helpers

Comment: and without view_context. it gives a link something like 

http://localhost:3000/wikis/1/pages/%3Ca%20href=%22/wikis/4/pages/1/revert%22%20data-method=%22post%22%20rel=%22nofollow%22%3Eundo%3C/a%3E

Comment: i have updated the question with the other method i am using controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave Newton said in the comments (+1), this belongs in a helper.

in `helpers/pages_helper.rb`:

```
module PagesHelper
  def undo_link
    # ...define view_context here...
    view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@page.versions.scoped.last), :method => :post)
  end
end
```

Note that you will need to define `view_context` before this will work, either in the space indicated, passing it in as an argument, or by using an instance variable accessible to the view at the time the helper method is called.

To call it in a view:

```
<%= undo_link %>
```

If you do this...

```
"#{undo_link}"
```

...you will get this:

```
 "<a href="/revert/version/path/...">undo</a>" # <= surrounded by quotes!
```

which will **not work**.

Comment: again a silly question i guess. but how do define view_context ?

Comment: I don't know what `view_context` is. You use it undefined in your controller also. This is your design, so you tell me... Where did `view_context` come from, and what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: well, view_context is basically used in the controllers where tags like link_to dont work. in short to bring the views tags to controller. Ryan bates used it here http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

Comment: After researching, `view_context` allows access to view methods in controllers. (learn something new every day!) Since helper methods _are_ view methods, you don't need it. Remove `view_context`, so your helper method contains only `link_to(...)`.

Comment: same here.. thanks, i just got back. I was thinking the same thing. will try it :)

Comment: do you know in my routes how can i keep `/:wiki_id/` constant. so it doesnt change when unod_link is in a loop (in the views)?

Comment: That's a different question altogether.